# Join with multiple queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query already:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `prefix_messages`
                        WHERE `category_id`=4
                        ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 30) ilv
         ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

How to use join query to add data from users table if in `prefix_messages` I have `user_id` column?

Thanx!

Comment: How can you imagine an answer without any knowledge of tables schema?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM   (SELECT pm.ID as prefixID, * FROM prefix_messages as pm
    INNER JOIN users as u
    ON pm.User_id = u.UserId
    WHERE pm.category_id=4
    ORDER BY pm.id DESC LIMIT 30)
    ORDER BY prefixID ASC
```

I assume that you are only doing the subselect because you want to reverse the order after you get the top 30?